# kendo ui combobox data-value-change parameter not working

Tags: mvvm, combobox, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI and using declarative bindings to binda element on a form. It uses the combo box widget to search for a list of options. The widget is actually performing as expected, however the search is only requested when the value has changed (this makes sense). The issue I have is the change event is only firing when the user blurs the combo box (e.g. by clicking outside the input).

This is to be expected due to the DOM change event firing after blurring, however the [Kendo UI docs state](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/value#using-the-data-value-update-attribute) that by using the 'data-value-update' parameter you can specify the event to fire on 'keyup'.

Unfortunately I cannot get this to work, here is the combobox HTML

```
<input data-role='combobox' data-bind="value: comboBoxValue, events: { change: methodToDoSearch}" data-value-update="keyup" type="text" data-text-field='Text' data-value-field='Id' />
```

This is being created as part of a kendo ui template (although I have tested outside of the template so this should not make a difference)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-value-update` attribute is supported only for vanilla textboxes (`<input type="text" />`). Kendo ComboBox raises its change event only when it loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the data-value-update is only meant to update the bound object the widget is applied to (when you enter something into the widget, the observable is updated with the value on the given event. In this case, keyup).

I.E., because the combobox widget can only be set to one of the combobox datasource values, it doesn't make sense for the observable to bind to a temporary non-combobox-value.

I haven't tried this, but what events can you bind to via the events binding? The Kendo demos show mouseover, click, etc. Perhaps try something like this:

```
<input data-role='combobox' data-bind="value: comboBoxValue, events: { change: methodToDoSearch, keyup: methodToDoSearch}" type="text" data-text-field='Text' data-value-field='Id' />
```

In general, what event do you want to fire on keyup? If you'd like to do some manual searching to change the datasource of the combobox on keyup, that's what I'd look in to.